# Will changing the field type from text area (long) to rich text area lose data?

Tags: configuration, data

The documentation says

> Changing from Text Area (Long) to any type except Email, Phone, Text, Text Area, or URL

does that mean rich text are will also retain the data?

Answer (score 2):

No it does say except text. You may lose data if the change the character limit to less than what it was previously.

I've just tested in a sandbox and no data was lost (I kept the character limit the same). You will likely need to change the number of lines shown and it will ask about field use in Visualforce pages...but data wise you are ok to go :)